# Make emacs always close html tags

Tags: emacs, sgml

How can I make emacs always close a sgml-tag (C-c-C-t)?

For example `div`, `h2` tags work fine but `p` or `li` do not.
Basically I'm looking for a way of specifing that I'm always using xhtml when I insert a tag.

Answer (score 8):

You need to turn on `sgml-xml-mode`:

> When non-nil, tag insertion functions will be XML-compliant.

`sgml-mode` attempts to guess whether your buffer is in XHTML (and so turn on `sgml-xml-mode` automatically) by looking at the doctype. See the function `sgml-xml-guess`. It's expecting to find the string `"XHTML"` somewhere in the DTD name.

If you can't get `sgml-xml-guess` to work, then you could turn on `sgml-xml-mode` explicitly. Perhaps like this:

```
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook #'(lambda nil (setq sgml-xml-mode t)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, but I can't explicitly call sgml-mode because 99% of the time I deal with rails template views (rhtml) or php files which have their own modes.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you explicitly call `sgml-mode`, but that you set `sgml-xml-mode` to `t` when editing HTML. `rhtml-mode` is derived from `html-mode`, so my hook ought to work for you.