# Why customize Emacs variable sgml-xml-mode in sgml-mode.el?

Tags: emacs, emacs23

As the title asks, why customize Emacs variable "sgml-xml-mode" (from file "sgml-mode.el")?  In "(define-derived-mode sgml-mode text-mode '(sgml-xml-mode "XML" "SGML")" there is the line "  (set (make-local-variable 'sgml-xml-mode) (sgml-xml-guess))" which makes that variable buffer local and which uses function "sgml-xml-guess" to give it a value, so what is customizing that variable good for?

For example, creating a buffer "new" and setting its mode to "html-mode" has the result that "sgml-xml-mode" has the local value nil--even if customization sets the global value to t.

The variable is defined thusly:

```
(defcustom sgml-xml-mode nil
  "When non-nil, tag insertion functions will be XML-compliant.
It is set to be buffer-local when the file has
a DOCTYPE or an XML declaration."
  :type 'boolean
  :version "22.1"
  :group 'sgml)
```

I am using:

> GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) of 2011-03-10 on 3249CTO

A related question is [Make emacs always close html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4265314/1264870).

Answer (score 0):

It's just a historical accident.  I"m not sure this question is appropriate here, BTW.